# Failed to instantiate module in application ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I make a simple application Ionic 2 but I find a problem that exists year screenshot

[image]

code index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
      <title></title>

      <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

      <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
      <script>
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
            .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
            .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
        }
      </script>-->

      <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
      <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
      -->

      <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
      <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

      <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
      <script src="cordova.js"></script>
      <!-- script home.js -->
      <script src="js/home.js"></script>

      <!-- your app's js -->
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">

      <ion-pane>
      <!--  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
          <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
        </ion-content> --><div ng-view></div>
      </ion-pane>
    </body>
  </html>
```

code home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>AngularJS & Firebase Web App</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">


    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="justified-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="../lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="../lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
      <h2>AngularJS & Firebase App!</h2>
    </div>
    <form class="form-signin" role="form">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <a href="#"> Sign Up</a>
      </label>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>

  </div>



  </body></html>
```

code home.js

```
    var app = angular.module('home', ['ionic'])

      .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

            // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
            // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
            // a much nicer keyboard experience.
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
          }
          if(window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
          }
        });
      })

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/home', { templateUrl : 'templates/home.html',controller: 'HomeCtrl' });
      }])

    app.controller('HomeCtrl', [function() {

    }]);
```

code app.js

```
  angular.module('myApp', ['ionic','home'])

  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

        // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
        // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
        // a much nicer keyboard experience.
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      }
      if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  })

  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
  }]);
```

I added ngRoute in js files but same problem